# How can I deploy an GWT appliacation larger than 150MB to GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

GWT creates permutations for each browser/locale etc. So you can easily end up with dozens of permutations for a single application and a such the total application size quickly exceeds 150MB.

Any workaround to be able to upload large GWT applications or are there any plans to increase this limit?

Comment: This feature request appears to be tracked in http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defeats the purpose of having multiple permutations, but one workaround is to use soft permutations to reduce the number of permutations.

e.g.: you can support all browsers and locales in a single permutation if you add

```
    <collapse-all-properties />
```

to your gwt.xml file.   A single permutations that covers all browsers and locales uses much less space than having separate permutations for every combination of browser and locale.  You can also have more fine grained control over the collapse of permutations by following the directions here - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations

At the end of the day, that is just a workaround to get around the 150MB limit though.  Collapsing permutations increases the download size for each individual users, as they would be downloading code for browsers and locales they are not currently using.  Ideally, the GAE team would increase the limit.